# A local key/value store for Windows

Tags: database, json, nosql-manager

Is there any equivalent of sqlite as a key/value store that will run on Windows? I have a bunch of data in JSON files that I'd love to be able to view and query like I can with relational tabular data with sqlite and a Windows client like [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). So far, I found plenty of libraries or embeddable databases, but no standalone package with a Windows client.

Any idea?

Comment: Isn't there a sqlite version for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you are asking for, but it's what I use.

When I want to do lightweight data management with a relational flavor,  I use MS Access.  It's fairly easy to load data into it, although I've never done that with JSON data.  It has a point and click interface for query building, although I prefer to use sql.  It has a good feature for establishing table links to data stored in some other DBMS.

The report writer is rather limited, but you can access a view from Excel and mess around that way.